# Running a systemd service unit at next boot, but not subsequent boots

Tags: systemd

I have a script that I want to run during my next system boot, but not on subsequent boots. I want to use systemd to launch it, so I created a service file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/myscript.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/mypackage/bin/myscript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can tell systemd to run this service at boot using `systemctl enable myscript.service`.

What do I need to do in order to stop it from running on subsequent boots?

I can add `systemctl disable myscript.service` to the end of my script, but then that always disables the service. If possible I would like to be able to enable the service, then start it, and still have it execute on next boot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the `ConditionPathExists=` directive (see `systemd.unit(5)`) to conditionally start a unit. This allows you to leave the unit permanently enabled and to (temporarily) disable it by deleting a simple file.

There is no distinction between "started at boot" and "started from `systemctl start`" in systemd. A workaround would be to check the uptime in your script in order to take the decision to enable/disable the unit on next boot (by deleting/creating the `ConditionPathExists=` file).

Answer (score 6):

> Note: this answer extends [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247015/80216) by [Timothée Ravier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/44535/timoth%c3%a9e-ravier)
> <sub><sup>(Timothée [previously used the name Siosm
> on this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20150921173758/https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/44535/siosm))</sup></sub>,
> and includes an alternative solution. 
> If you agree with the first part, please up vote Timothée’s answer instead.

In vein with [Timothée Ravier’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247015/80216),
use `ConditionPathExists=` in section `[Unit]` of the unit’s service file
(see systemd.unit(5) [at freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conditions%20and%20Asserts) or [at man7.org](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html#%5BUNIT%5D_SECTION_OPTIONS))
in order to make the running of your service conditional.

For instance, if `myscript`’s responsibility
is to create a file or a folder once, add startup conditions
that reflect this: `ConditionPathExists=!/path/to/folder`. 
Note the **`!`**, which negates (inverts) the sense of the condition;
the service unit is started only if the path does not exist.

Conversely, you can have the `ConditionPathExists` point to a file
such as `/var/tmp/myscript.on-next-reboot` that the script
is tasked to remove after running successfully. 
You can probably add the removal as the unit’s `ExecStartPost=` directive.

---

In general, though, you should try to work your system so that after-reboot actions are not necessary. Setting things to run at next boot is very "Windows-like" in attitude. Linux users and administrators tend to favor deterministic, modular and previsible boots; having conditional run-time values trigger different paths of boot makes boot system much harder to reason about, and it makes it more prone to breakage.