# Resume Bash Script After Reboot

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, reboot

I have a bash script that changes some configuration in OS and database and it needs reboot then other commands are needed to be run. something like this:

```
 newvalue1=
 ip=
 .
 .
 some commands
 .
 .
 reboot
 .
 .
 some other commands
```

what to do to make this happen?

(there are 2 other questions like this on stack exchange, [Q1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145294/how-to-continue-a-script-after-it-reboots-the-machine) and [Q2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249499/install-script-with-restart-and-continue) but they were asked long time ago and users are no longer active to ask them questions. i asked again to find out if there is new ideas and answers)

Comment: Which distribution, version, etc.?

Comment: @muru Centos 6.7 and 6.9 and 7.6

Comment: CentOS 6 released 3 years before Ubuntu 14.04 did. Not a release for new ideas. CentOS 7, perhaps. Systemd might have something new. Better add that to the question.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233300/running-a-systemd-service-unit-at-next-boot-but-not-subsequent-boots/268268

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify the script and if you can use `crontab`, then you might use the `@reboot` timing in `crontab` to rerun the script. The behaviour of the script would be dual, depending on how it's called. So eg. if it's run with a parameter `-s` or `--second-run`, then it would do the after-reboot stuff. Introducing two main functions in the script like `first_run` and `second_run` would help organise it. Here's a sketch of the script:

1. Check how it's called (with or without the `-s` parameter).
2. If without `-s`:

   a) Do the initial stuff.

   b) Add the second run with `@reboot` to crontab.

   c) Reboot.
3. If with `-s`:

   a) Do the after-reboot stuff.

   b) Remove the rerun from crontab.

Comment: would you pleade add a proper example ?

Comment: @BlackCrystal It's quite complex, so rather not. My answer is supposed to be a sketch. I have no CentOS also, so could not test anythow.

Comment: i wrote a script inspired by your answer, those 2 question and @muru comments and it worked. finally!