# Button/script to reboot, then shut it down automatically?

Tags: upgrade, shutdown, software-updates

There is a possibility to reboot linux - which means it shuts down, then start again just after.
How could I reboot, then shut it down? (which means shutdown, start, shutdown).

Some distros updates now during startups - so by rebooting then shutting down, I can install updates when I don't need my computer. It means I don't have to wait 5 minutes at startup for updates.

Of course I've thought about creating a system with a flag to do so (check 10 minutes after startup if a file "flag exists". If yes, delete it and shut down the computer... Next time I want to reboot+shutdown, I use the script that creates the flag).

But is there a better way? A safer way? A more generic way?

In the end, I'll use it as a button.

Distro: KDE neon
use: personal computer

Comment: Not sure why you'd boot just to shut down again. IIRC windows will apply some updates during boot, causing long boots and so it could make sense there.  But that isn't a thing with most (all?) linux distros.

Comment: Alas, some do @Stewart, to my grand dismay.

Comment: You could make a cron entry with `@reboot` as time that also removes itself. Alteranativeley a systemd service, that disables itself after running

Comment: I don't think you need to wait after the startup; If I understand correctly, after a reboot KDE neon applies the patches and then reboots again. Anyway, for any action you want to do once after reboot, you can try the suggestion in [the following answer][https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247015/273579]: Create a service the depends on the exitance of the file; When the file exists (if you created it before the reboot), the service will run a script that would delete the file and shut down the system. If you want to be sure, you can add a "sleep" to the script to shut down after certain time.